# InR , multiple age pyramids using pyramidlattice {Giza}

Tags: r

I am trying to compare more that one age pyramids in only one frame. I was looking for some example using traditional packages like ggplot but, I did not finded it.

Do you have some option?

The unique able to compare is Package ‘Giza’. This package has some difficulty for find others examples... the only I can find is the following

```
data(EduDat)
data(dictionary)
# select the desired year, country, and education-scenario from EduDat
Years <- c(2010,2030,2050)
Countries <- c("Pakistan","Bangladesh","Indonesia")
Scenarios <- c("GET")
# the male-column needs to be flipped
iEduDat <- subset(EduDat,match(cc,getcode(Countries,dictionary)) & match(yr,Years) & match(scen2,Scenarios))
iEduDat$value[iEduDat$sex == "Male"] <- (-1) * iEduDat$value[iEduDat$sex == "Male"]

agegrs <- paste(seq(15,100,5),seq(19,104,5),sep="-")
agegrs[length(agegrs)] <- "100+"

lattice.options(axis.padding = list(numeric=0))
x <- pyramidlattice(agegr ~ value| factor(sex,levels=c("Male","Female")) *
                                   factor(cc,levels=getcode(Countries,dictionary),labels=Countries) *
                                   factor(yr,levels=Years,labels=Years),
           groups=variable,data=iEduDat,layout=c(length(Countries)*2,length(Years)),
           type="l",lwd=1,xlab="Population",ylab="Age",main="Population by Highest Level of Education",
           strip=TRUE,par.settings = simpleTheme(lwd=3,col=colors()[c(35,76,613,28)]),box.width=1,
           scales=list(alternating=3,tick.number=5,relation="same",y=list(at=1:length(4:21),labels=agegrs)),
           auto.key=list(text=c("No-edu","Primary","Secondary","Tertiary"),reverse.row=TRUE,
                           points=FALSE,rectangles=TRUE,space="right",columns=1,border=FALSE,
                           title="ED-Level",cex.title=1.1,lines.title=2.5,padding.text=1,background="white"),
           prepanel=prepanel.default.bwplot2,panel=function(...){
                    panel.grid(h=length(agegrs),v=5,col="lightgrey",lty=3)
                    panel.pyramid(...)
                   })

x # with strips for every factor over each panel
# useOuterStrips(x) # with outer strips, but only in case of two factors
useOuterStrips2(x) # with outer strips in case of three factors
```

[image]

Now, I would like to do some modications... for example, I would like to change the colors between the years panels. The most important modification that I want is axis x limits. I am trying to do something like this(scale parameter)

```
scales= list(x = list( relation = "free" , limits = list( c(-85000,85000) ,  c(-260000,260000) , c(-260000,260000)) ) ,  y = list(relation="same", at=1:length(agegrs)) ).
```

But this results in a error:

```
Error in abs(x$x.limits) : non-numeric argument to mathematical function
In addition: Warning message:
In valid.charjust(just) : reached elapsed time limit
```

Comment: That appears to be a lattice-system plotting function. To suggest that it is not as "traditional" is kind of amusing.

Comment: After looking at the code for `pyramidlattice`, `pyramid2.formula`, and `prepanel.default.bwplot2` , I'm thinking the authors of Giza never intended for you to do any tweaking of the xlim or ylim settings. They get set up in multiple places and appears to me they also get scaled. You may need to trim values in the data, as you well might have needed to do with a ggplot2 special purpose function that attempted to do this as well.

Comment: (You might want to correspond with the package authors.)